# Chat multi-user bug

Tags: support, chat, multiple-accounts

On all sites but Cooking.SE, I'm (my user is) GUI-Junkie. On the [UX.SE chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1587439#1587439), I'm BaffledCook.

Comment: I'm always getting the 'support' tag wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What exactly is the bug? I believe your chat username is based on what account is set as the parent user. You have the most reputation on cooking, so it must have chosen that one.

If you open up any chat and click your username you can see the parent user listed on your profile and change it to an account that has GUI Junkie as the username.

Comment: This is right; the parent user is set to Cooking. [Profile link](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/18015/baffledcook)

Comment: Well, when I'm on the UX chat, I want to be GUI-Junkie. On the cooking chat, I want to be BaffledCook. This is basic concordance between chat and main and meta sites (as I see it).

Comment: I just changed my user name, but it would be a pain to have to do it every time I want to chat here or there.

Comment: @GUI Junkie, you could always try for a feature-request (if one doesn't already exist for this), but as far as I know it's not possible to have multiple chat usernames.

Comment: OK, I'll do that. I'm having lots of success with feature requests :)